# After intent to show image not all functions appear

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm going to develop a simple app to list .jpg files and after a click call an `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, below the code:

```
File imageFile = new File(filename);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imageFile), "image/jpeg");
startActivity(i);
```

The intent works properly, in fact in app I receive the message to select an app to show the selected image. But I noticed that after the choice, for example with Google Photos, not all function are enabled. For example the share function is not visible, has someone already noticed this behavior?

Some other details; if I choose Google Photos I only have the "Info" and "Guide and Feedback" options. If I choose gallery app (I have a Samsung Ace 3) I have only "Info" and "Set as wallpaper" options.

Note: if I open the same image directly from Google Photos all functions are enabled...

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The `ACTION_VIEW` intent calls another application to view the content that you present, in your case a JPEG image. If there is more than on application that can handle that `Intent`, Android lets the user choose an app to display the image. Once the application receives the `Intent`, it is up to that application to display the content how it sees fit.

Basically, you have no control over what functions are available with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`. If you want more control, you can create your own `Activity` in which you can view the image and provide whatever functions you would like.